# CMake Error at 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:27 (ocv_include_directories): Unknown CMake command "ocv_include_directories"

Tags: c, opencv, cmake

Right, so I'm trying to build a project in VS2012 and I've been chasing down various errors for the past 2 days...I'm coming in on a lot of legacy code, and it deals with OpenCV2.1

So after chasing down all the 3rd party files I needed, I now get the following error:
error C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'cmakedefine' c:\opencv2.1\3rdparty\libtiff\tif_config.h

Line:

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the <assert.h> header file. */
#cmakedefine HAVE_ASSERT_H
```

Which the only help I found here:
[cannot compile allegro using visual c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309113/cannot-compile-allegro-using-visual-c)

suggesting that I need to rebuild OpenCV with cmake.  At which point I get the error:

```
CMake Error at 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:27 (ocv_include_directories):   Unknown CMake command "ocv_include_directories".
```

In the visual editor.  So I traced that to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146650/compiling-opencv-samples-unknown-cmake-command-ocv-check-dependencies).

So I run it in command line as:

```
cmake C:/OpenCV2.1 -DBUILD_SAMPLES=ON
```

Which spits out more errors:
    CMake Error at 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
      project PROJECT called with incorrect number of arguments

```
CMake Error at 3rdparty/libtiff/CMakeLists.txt:27 (ocv_include_directories):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_include_directories".
```

I can't find any documentation for ocv_include_directories.  I've tried following multiple OpenCV cmake tutorials, but haven't had any success.

Comment: I don't know OpenCV, but you should run cmake with the generator specified: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 11" c:\OpenCV2.1`. The `ocv_include_directories` seems to be a helper function that OpenCV defines and is included somewhere with `include(SomeOpenCVUtilFile)`. I have no clue, why OpenCV can't find it.

Comment: I think I must have mixed it in somehow when trying to find the correct combination of packages.  I'm just going to start over from scratch again.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was actually that I had visual studio 2012, and the codebase I was working in was visual studio 2008 built.  There was no possibility to ever track down all of these errors.  Solution was to uninstall 2012 and install 2008.